# Metropolis custom footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, logos, beamer-metropolis

How could we have a footline as follows?

Author's name (Inst)  [space] Title  [space] slide's number

Could the title be centered between author's details and slide's number?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute) \hspace*{4cm} \insertshorttitle}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=gray}

\author{names}
\institute{institute}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please separate your second question: Your current title and start of the body refer to the footer. Please ask the question which focuses on the header as separate post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\hfill` instead of custom spaces.

[image: footer]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)\hfill\insertshorttitle}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=gray}

\author{names}
\institute{institute}
\title{Quack}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```